# What happened to the Menu Order option for posts (for ordering posts by Menu Order in Block Editor (Gutenberg)?

Tags: block-editor, menu-order

Current WordPress version: 6.2.3

Hi, I have around 45 posts assigned "Attorney" category. I have to arrange them by last name (which is not possible) from the post title alone or with ID or with Date as well.
So, I was thinking to use WordPress old Menu Order option, where we can give each post a number. But I do not see such option now since every post now is edited by Block Editor (Gutenberg)?

Did we remove the menu order option, did it now became legacy thing?

Do not need any extra plugin for it though, just wondering we had that functionality before and now it is gone

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Post Attributes option for Posts has to be added manually.
By adding

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_support_for_posts_order' );

function add_support_for_posts_order() 
{
    add_post_type_support( 'post', 'page-attributes' );
}
```

However, page has a support by default. So, only "post" is to be supported.

Comment: This is correct, but just so you're aware, this has always been the case. It's not something new with the block editor.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes. It was always like this. I got confused. You are correct it has always been the case.